# Mapping the sentences, which are of variable length to particular key

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie to Python as well as to this forum. Below is the question

The file is as mentioned in the image
[File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY42E.png).
I'm able to split the text in text2 column and write to different rows with the below code

```
myfile=open('Output.csv,'w')
wr=csv.writer(myfile,lineterminator='\n')
df=pd.read_excel("Input.xlsx")

for txt in df['Text2']:
   sentence.append(txt.split('.'))
for pharse in sentence:
    for words in pharse:
        wr.writerow([words])
```

I need a help on how to map the sentences, which are of variable length to the key.Also, how to achieve the specific format as mentioned in attached image file.
Also, the writerow function starts writing in the first row but how to specify to begin with column three.

Any help on this is much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm assuming the missing `'` on `'Output.csv` is just a cut&paste error.

Comment: @AChampion.Yes. It's just the copy ans paste error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myfile = open('Output.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, lineterminator='\n')
entries = {}
for k, txt1, txt2 in df.values:
    sentences = [s.strip() for s in txt2.split('.') if len(s.strip()) > 0]
    # sentences = [s.strip() + '.' for s in txt2.split('.') if len(s.strip()) > 0]
    entries[k] = [txt1, sentences]
for k in entries.keys():
    txt1, txt2 = entries[k]
    wr.writerow([k, txt1, txt2[0]])
    for s in txt2[1:]:
        wr.writerow(['', '', s])
myfile.close()
```

Use alternative `sentences = ...` line (the line commented in the above code) if you want to have a dot at the end of each sentence in the csv file. From your example image it is not clear what needs to happen to the dot (sometimes it appears in the output and sometimes it does not).

Also, if so desired, the code can be further simplified by combining the two loops into one loop:

```
myfile = open('Output.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(myfile,lineterminator='\n')
for k, txt1, txt2 in df.values:
    sentences = [s.strip() for s in txt2.split('.') if len(s.strip()) > 0]
    wr.writerow([k, txt1, sentences[0]])
    for s in sentences[1:]:
        wr.writerow([None,'',s])
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the help!! Could you help me on how to map the sentences in text2 column to the key value. To be more specific if key value is 1  and after splitting the sentences to different rows if the number of sentence are 5, all the sentences must have the same key value. The key value changes as you can see in the file format.